# 枕头 versus 垫子, are these different?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

I've come across these two words in a picture-book. Are  枕头 and 垫子 the same kind of pillow or are they different kinds of pillow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

枕头(Zhen Tou) is the pillow which is on your bed. That's the only meaning of that word.
However, 垫子(Dian Zi) usually means a mat or pad which you are sitting on. Or means some pad could be put under a glass cup, for instance.